# Laravel 8: Role ID Does Not Submitted Into One To Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 for my project, and in this project, I want to apply **OneToMany** relationship between `users` and `roles` tables.

So at the Models, I've added these:

`Role.php`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
}
```

`User.php`:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then for creating new users, I've added this form field:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="role" dir="ltr">
       @foreach(\App\Models\Role::all() as $role)
         <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

And at the Store method, I coded this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'status' => 'required',
        'role' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ])->validated();

    $creation = User::create([
        'name' => $validate_data['name'],
        'email' => $validate_data['email'],
        'status' => $validate_data['status'],
        'role_id' => $validate_data['role'],
        'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password'])
    ]);

    if($creation){
        return redirect()->back();
    }else{
        return '1003';
    }
}
```

But now the problem is, whenever I try to add a new user, it will be added successfully to the table `users` but the column `role_id` will remain empty:

[image]

And when I say `dd($request);` it prints this:

[image]

As you can see it stores the `role` but I don't know why it does not save it in the database!

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't have `role_id` as a `$fillable` on your model.

```
class User {
    $fillable = [
        ...,
        'role_id',
    ];
}
```

Filling relationships as a property is not optimal, it can lead to relationships being null, even thou you just populated the data. The correct approach is to use `associate()` method call. This also provides the benefit of returning a 404 if role is not found, because you have to fetch the Role before `associating()` it. In most `API's`, this would be the standard if a relation is not present and just more sturdy code, to avoid foreign key errors from `SQL`.

```
$user = new User([
    'name' => $validate_data['name'],
    'email' => $validate_data['email'],
    'status' => $validate_data['status'],
    'password' => bcrypt($validate_data['password'])
]);

$user->associate(Role::findOrFail($validate_data['role']));
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this mistake too previously, I believe this might be because you forgot to add `role_id` to the `$fillable` variable in `User.php` model.